# Calculate surface area of $z = x^2, \quad 0 \leq y \leq x \leq 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

> Calculate surface area of $z = x^2, \quad 0 \leq y \leq x \leq 1$

**My attempt**:

I parametrize the surface with 
$$r(x,y) = (x,y,x^2),$$
where the domain E is given by: 
$$0 \leq x\leq1,$$
$$0 \leq y \leq x.$$
I find $|r'_x \times r'_y|$:
$$|r'_x \times r'_y|$$
$$|(1,0,2x) \times (0,1,0)|= |(-2x,0,1)| = \sqrt{4x^2+1}$$

The area is given by 
$$\iint_E(\sqrt{4x^2+1})dxdy,$$
but I can't compute this integral and it doesn't seem to be computable with reasonable complexity according to wolfram alpha.

**What am I doing wrong?** The answer is supposed to be: $\frac{5\sqrt{5}-1}{12}$

Comment: $\int\int_E \sqrt{4x^2 +1} dx dy = \int_0^1 \int_y^1 \sqrt{4x^2 + 1} dx dy = \int_0^1 \int_0^x \sqrt{4x^2 +1} dy dx = \int_0^1 x \sqrt{4x^2 + 1}dx$

Comment: @Cauchy Thanks, that solved it. Well this was an unnecessary question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S={\iint_{E}{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}dxdy}$$
$$S={\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^{x}\sqrt{1+4x^2}dydx}$$
$$S={\int_{x=0}^{1}\sqrt{1+4x^2}dx}{\int_{y=0}^xdy}$$
$$S={\int_{x=0}^{1}{x\sqrt{1+4x^2}}dx}$$
By substitution $1+4x^2=u^2$$\implies$ $4xdx=udu$
$$S={\int_{u=1}^{\sqrt5}{u^2\over4}du}$$
$${S} = {(5\sqrt5-1)\over{12}}$$